# Node js is showing old file in the console even after making changes in it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a file and looking for changes in it in real time using fs.watch which is working correctly. Now I want to make a call to app.get every time my file gets changed. But my function "func_read_file_lines" is still sending the old file to back. I can't find the problem.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
require('log-timestamp');
path = require("path");
var filename = path.resolve('test.txt');
const buttonPressesLogFile = filename;


fs.watch(buttonPressesLogFile, (event, filename) => {
    if (filename && event === 'change') {
        console.log(`${filename} file Changed`);
        func_read_file_lines.
        then((data) => {
            let last_n_lines = data.split('\n').slice(-10, -1);
            console.log(last_n_lines)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
});

let func_read_file_lines = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(data)
        }
    });
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    func_read_file_lines.
    then((data) => {
        let last_n_lines = data.split('\n').slice(-10, -1);

        res.render('display', {
            last_n_lines: last_n_lines
        });

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})


const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you only create `func_read_file_lines` once. Try creating a function to return the promise like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
require('log-timestamp');
path = require("path");
var filename = path.resolve('test.txt');
const buttonPressesLogFile = filename;


fs.watch(buttonPressesLogFile, (event, filename) => {
    if (filename && event === 'change') {
        console.log(`${filename} file Changed`);
        func_read_file_lines.
        then((data) => {
            let last_n_lines = data.split('\n').slice(-10, -1);
            console.log(last_n_lines)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
});

// CHANGE THE LINE BELOW
let func_read_file_lines = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(data)
        }
    });
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    func_read_file_lines(). // CHANGED THIS LINE
    then((data) => {
        let last_n_lines = data.split('\n').slice(-10, -1);

        res.render('display', {
            last_n_lines: last_n_lines
        });

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})


const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I tried lots of different things but never paid attention whether it is a function or not.